# How to create new reference section at top of the home page Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, reference

I want to create a new reference section at top of the home page using a module.

[Tut on Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/) the method mention here is working, but I want to do this by module so that when i install the module new reference will be created.

I want to show a mini slider (which contains some text) at top of the page (`Every Page`).

I created a slider in `phtml` file of `my module`.

Now i want to insert this phtml file at top of the page.

All these things will happen as one install the extension.

In `config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Maddyboy_Instagramapi>
      <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Maddyboy_Instagramapi>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <instagramapi>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Maddyboy_Instagramapi</module>
            <frontName>instagramapi</frontName>
          </args>
      </instagramapi>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <instagramapi>
              <file>instagramapi.xml</file>
            </instagramapi>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
```

In
`/magento1/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/instagramapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.3"> 
<default>
     <reference name="header">
            <block type="instagramapi/apislider" name="instagramapi_apislider" template="instagramapi/apislider.phtml" />
        </reference>
</default>
```

In `header.phtml`

```
<?php echo "hello",$this->getChildHtml('instagramapi_apislider') ?>
```

**Update**
`As suggested by @Yiorgos Moschovitis`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.3"> 
<default>
     <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="instagramapi/apislider" name="instagramapi_apislider" before="-" output="toHtml" template="instagramapi/apislider.phtml" />
     </reference>
</default>
```

Still not working.

**Update 2**

```
<default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
      <block type="core/template" name="instagramapi_apislider" before="-" output="toHtml" template="instagramapi/apislider.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
```

This code working.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you want to make a module that adds a block in the header block of only the cms home page ? A referenece is used to add a new block in an existing one. The you can reference the new one as well...

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis I updated my question sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your modules config.xml be sure that you have

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <mymodule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Namespace_Mymodule</module>
                <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </mymodule>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule>
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then your /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mymodule.xml

should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="slider" template="slider.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Now open your templates /template/page/html/header.phtml

and add the following line wherever you want it to show

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider') ?>
```

--- Edit ---

If you don't want to use the getChildHtml() function then header is not the right place to place your block. Instead, if you want it to the top of your page, use 'after_body_start' as a reference and 'output="toHtml"' in your block tag.

i.e. your mymodule.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="slider"   before="-" output="toHtml" template="slider.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: is there any way to call this  `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('slider') ?>` by module itself

Comment: Or is there any way to call a static block in header by using module  ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested , still no block content shown

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Are you sure that your config.xml is correct? For example <mymodule> should be replaced by toyur modules frontName. 
Do you have any experience with config.xml or should I walk you a bit more?

Comment: I updated the answer. Be sure to replace mymodule and Namespace_Mymodule with your actual values

Comment: still not working sir

Comment: its woking now , it was a sily mistake at type 'type="core/template"

Comment: Yeah I thought it would be sth like this. Glad to be of service.